# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in hive

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, github, hive

i got sample program of hive in this below url.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/hadoop/hive

When i export the project and run the application got below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at com.oreilly.springdata.hadoop.hive.HiveApp.main(HiveApp.java:29)
```

Can any one know this.Thnaks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: 1.8 java version is installed in my system

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work with 1.8. Try 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 1.6. The code you are trying to use is using Spring 3, which is made for Java 1.6. It will not work if built with Java 1.8 as target.

You can target Java 1.6 even if you only have Java 1.8 in theory using [this](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2017/03/10/run-eclipse-ide-on-one-version-of-java-but-target-another/).

Also, [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8) is a great article on Spring versions and JRE compatibility.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hiveServer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.

Comment: @SumeetTiwari If the question is solved you can mark my answer as correct with the green arrow, and ask you new question in a new thread.